# ¿Cómo puedo ordenar con For? (PHP)

Tags: php

He estado viendo que utilizar para mi página de tops, y me recomendaron **For()**, lo que quiero hacer es que por orden se le asigne una placa/imágen a cada usuario, es decir:

**Al primer usuario se le asigne la imagen Silver.png; Al segundo se le asigne la imagen Bronze.png; a los demás (desde el 3 en adelante) se le asigne la imagen Up.png**. Maso menos intente hacerlo, pero no sé por qué que me sale el error de Maximum execution.

```
                for($i = 1; $i < 3; $i++){
                    if($i == 1){ $i = "silver";}
                    else if($i == 2){ $i = "bronze";}
                    else{ $i= "up";}
                }
                $badge = $i;

                echo '<img src="../images/web-gallery/v2/images/halloffame/'.$badge.'.png">';
```

Código completo del function()

```
public static function TopsCredits(){
        global $db, $light, $users;
        $topsDb = $db->query("SELECT id,credits,look,username FROM users WHERE credits ORDER BY credits ASC LIMIT 4");
        $oddEven = "odd";
        if($topsDb){
            while($topsUsers = $topsDb->fetch_assoc()){
                if($oddEven != "even") {
                    $oddEven = "even";
                }
                else {
                    $oddEven = "odd";
                }
                    // Parámetros
                $credits = number_format($topsUsers['credits']);
                $username = $topsUsers['username'];

                for($i = 1; $i <= 4; $i++){
                    if($i == 1){ $badge = "gold";}
                    else if($i == 2){ $badge = "silver";}
                    else if($i == 3){ $badge = "bronze";}
                    else { $badge = "up";}
                }

                echo '<li class="'.$oddEven.'">
                <div style="float:left;margin-left: -10px">
                    <img src="https://www.habbo.com/habbo-imaging/avatarimage?figure=fa-987462888-91.ea-3484-92.lg-281-110.ha-990000122-92-92.cc-874624568-3072.he-987462840-3072.hr-990000101-1407.ch-267-110.hd-3093-4.sh-3621-92-110&direction=2&head_direction=2&gesture=sml&headonly=1&size=b&img_format=gif">
                    </div>

                    <div class="info-top" id="list-up">
                    <a href="/user/'.$username.'" class="name">'.$username.'</a><br>
                        <a class="dinero">'.$credits.'</a>
                       <div class="up">
                    <img src="../images/web-gallery/v2/images/halloffame/'.$badge.'.png">
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </li>';
            }
        }
    }
```

Ejemplo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: el bucle for deberías recorrerlo para cada usuario y en cada una de esas iteraciones sobre los usuarios evaluar cuanto vale $badge para cada usuario. Como es la variable $usuarios que hace referencia a estos? es un objeto, array, variable que defines una y otra vez en algún otro bucle?

Comment: Sólo tengo una variable '$username' para todo, entonces no serviría hacer el método que dices.

Comment: De tu código que acabas de publicar, que valor o variable utilizas para asignar la posición al usuario?. el numero de créditos?, la posición devuelta por la consulta sql?

Comment: El número de créditos, es un top de créditos como se muestra en la imagen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ojo, el error de Maximum execution es debido a que tu for nunca concluye, esto es porque estas usando la misma variable ($i) para controlar tu ciclo for, como para asignar el valor de la posición que deseas y eso es un grave error.

Debes utilizar una variable para controlar tu for y otra diferente para almacenar el valor de la posición, tu código debería quedar así:

```
for($i = 1; $i < 3; $i++){
    if($i == 1){ $badge = "silver";}
    else if($i == 2){ $badge = "bronze";}
    else{ $badge= "up";}
    echo '<img src="../images/web-gallery/v2/images/halloffame/'.$badge.'.png">';
}
```

Ok ahora se entiende mucho mejor, no es necesario usar un for para asignar la posición según los créditos, dado que desde tu consulta sql ya traes ordenados a tus usuarios lo único que hay que tener es una variable que nos de en que usuario (posicion) se encuentra el bucle while, tu código debería quedar como sigue:

```
public static function TopsCredits(){
        global $db, $light, $users;
        $topsDb = $db->query("SELECT id,credits,look,username FROM users WHERE credits ORDER BY credits ASC LIMIT 4");
        $oddEven = "odd";
        if($topsDb){
            //Variable que usaremos para saber la posicion
            $pos_usuario = 1;
            while($topsUsers = $topsDb->fetch_assoc()){
                if($oddEven != "even") {
                    $oddEven = "even";
                }
                else {
                    $oddEven = "odd";
                }
                // Parámetros
                $credits = number_format($topsUsers['credits']);
                $username = $topsUsers['username'];

                //dado que solo nos interesa saber las tres primeras posiciones, convertimos el for en un switch
                switch($pos_usuario){
                    //primera posicion
                    case 1: $badge = "gold"; break;
                    //segunda posicion
                    case 2: $badge = "silver"; break;
                    //tercera posicion
                    case 3: $badge = "bronze"; break;
                    //demas posiciones
                    default: $badge = "up"; break;
                }

                echo '<li class="'.$oddEven.'">
                <div style="float:left;margin-left: -10px">
                <img src="https://www.habbo.com/habbo-imaging/avatarimage?figure=fa-987462888-91.ea-3484-92.lg-281-110.ha-990000122-92-92.cc-874624568-3072.he-987462840-3072.hr-990000101-1407.ch-267-110.hd-3093-4.sh-3621-92-110&direction=2&head_direction=2&gesture=sml&headonly=1&size=b&img_format=gif">
                </div>

                <div class="info-top" id="list-up">
                <a href="/user/'.$username.'" class="name">'.$username.'</a><br>
                <a class="dinero">'.$credits.'</a>
                <div class="up">
                <img src="../images/web-gallery/v2/images/halloffame/'.$badge.'.png">
                </div>
                </div>
                </li>';
                //No olvides aumentar en uno la variable del pos_usuario
                $pos_usuario++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ahora sí funciona, pero sólo sale la placa/imagen bronze.png para todos los usuarios, y debería ir en este orden(gold,silver,bronze, y desde allí en adelante up)

Comment: Ok, pero ahora para poder ver el nuevo error, te pido por favor que modifiques tu pregunta para que incluyas el código de como tienes ahora tu For, o en su caso, el código o los valores de tus usuarios, los cuales usas dentro de las condiciones para sacar las posiciones.

Comment: Dame un momento, mostraré una imagen de muestra también.

Comment: Gracias amigo, funciona la perfección.